# Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting the error "unable to get property style of null reference" as the value of "a" comes as null in IE 11. But the same code works fine in IE 8. the element a is very clearly defined in the div tag. Not sure what is the issue here.

```
document.getElementById("a").style.display = "block";

<div id="a" style="display:none"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
```

Comment: Could it be a timing issue where you trying to access the element before it was added to the document?

Comment: if that is the case,it should have been an issue in IE 8 as well.is that correct? i also tried placing the document.getelement after the div tag in the .jsp file...but no luck

Comment: In an ideal world all browsers have consistent behavior. In reality the spec left a lot of room for interpretation. try to execute the call after the document is ready: `window.onload = function () { document.getElementById("a").style.display = "block"; };`. this is why jQuery became so popular - it well abstracts the DOM and different browsers quirks.

Comment: what document mode are you in with your IE11?

Comment: Check your HTML (the part which is not shown here). It seems, that IE becomes worse version by version when parsing invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing start  `"` in attribute `src`

```
<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo... i have updated the post with the quote.the quote is available in the code. that is not the issue.  In IE 11, somehow the document.getElementbyId is not getting the element value and it is coming as null in IE11. but in IE8 this code works perfectly.